# Access Query (and likely SQL): When joining two tables, how do you prevent repeated values from the first table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I should preface by saying I have no SQL experience. I've tried watching videos and reading tutorials, but I've found I need a greater general understanding before I can actually understand what's happening.

Here's where I'm at currently;

## Orders

[image]

## Forecast

[image]

## Fiscal Calendar

[image]

---

---

## Desired Join Query

```
     Date    ||  Part Number  ||  Order QTY  ||  Forecast QTY
  10/9/2017  ||     AAA001    ||     200     ||      200
  10/9/2017  ||     AAA002    ||     400     ||      100
  10/9/2017  ||     AAA003    ||             ||       50
  10/9/2017  ||     AAA004    ||             ||      500
```

## How the Join Query is currently

[image]

---

---

Here's my **Design View** of the query, and below it is my **SQL**. Can someone assist in adjusting the SQL to make this fit the desired query?

[image]

## SQL of the Query

```
SELECT [Fiscal Calendar].Date, Orders.[Part Number], 
    Orders.QTY, Forecast.QTY
FROM ([Fiscal Calendar] LEFT JOIN 
    Forecast 
    ON [Fiscal Calendar].Date = Forecast.Date
    ) LEFT JOIN 
    Orders ON [Fiscal Calendar].Date = Orders.Date
GROUP BY [Fiscal Calendar].Date, Orders.[Part Number], Orders.QTY, Forecast.QTY;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are accomplishing with the Fiscal Calendar, but here is the route I would take:

```
SELECT [Fiscal Calendar].DATE,
    Forecast.[Part Number],
    Sum(Orders.Qty) AS [Order QTY],
    Sum(Forecast.Qty) AS [Forcast QTY]
FROM [Fiscal Calendar]
INNER JOIN (
    Forecast LEFT JOIN Orders ON (Forecast.DATE = Orders.DATE)
    AND (Forecast.[Part Number] = Orders.[Part Number])
) ON [Fiscal Calendar].DATE = Forecast.DATE
GROUP BY [Fiscal Calendar].DATE,
Forecast.[Part Number];
```

Comment: I thought this worked, but I've just noticed an issue with this setup; if there are any dates that have NULL for the Forecast QTY, it will not show a row (even if there *is* a QTY greater than zero for Orders). So, if a part on 10/10/17 has 200 ordered but 0 forecasted, it will not show up on this table. I've wrapped the expressions in nz(___, 0), but it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `JOIN` condition.  I also think you need some more aggregation:

```
SELECT [Fiscal Calendar].Date, Forecast.[Part Number],
       SUM(Orders.QTY), Forecast.QTY
FROM ([Fiscal Calendar] LEFT JOIN
      Forecast
      ON [Fiscal Calendar].Date = Forecast.Date
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Orders
     ON [Fiscal Calendar].Date = Orders.Date AND
        Forecast.[Part Number] = Orders.[Part Number]
GROUP BY [Fiscal Calendar].Date, Forecast.[Part Number], Forecast.QTY;
```

EDIT:

I think you can do what you want with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT [Fiscal Calendar].Date, Forecast.[Part Number],
       (SELECT SUM(Orders.QTY)
        FROM Orders
        WHERE [Fiscal Calendar].Date = Orders.Date AND
              Forecast.[Part Number] = Orders.[Part Number]
       ) as QTY,
       Forecast.QTY
FROM [Fiscal Calendar] LEFT JOIN
     Forecast
     ON [Fiscal Calendar].Date = Forecast.Date;
```

Comment: Using your SQL, I get the error "JOIN expression not supported". I initially copied/pasted, but I also went word-by-word on my original SQL and changed things as I went along. Same issue. *Edit:* It appears to be an issue using "AND" on the second LEFT JOIN. Not sure how to fix.